# Button onClick is not working in my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I was making an Amazon clone and the add to cart button is not working.** I was rending this is home component and getting all these props from there only. Somebody, please help. I was stuck there for 2 days only.
Any help is appreciated.
???

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Product.css";
import {useStateValue} from './StateProvider';

function Product({id, title, price, rating, image}) {

    const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    function addToCart(event) {

        console.log(event);

        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
            item: {

                id: id,

                title: title,
                image: image,
                price: price,
                rating: rating
            },
        });

    };


   
    return (
        <div className="product">
           
            <div className='product__info'>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p className='product__price'>
                    <small>₹</small>
                    <strong>{price}</strong>

                </p>
                <div className='product__rating'>
                    {
                        Array(rating)
                            .fill()
                            .map((_, i) => (<p>⭐</p>))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src={image} alt=''/>
            <button onClick={addToCart}>Add to cart</button>

        </div>
    );
}

    
export default Product
```

Comment: You probably need to show your action codes. Also probably a good idea to elaborate on what you mean by "not working"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the call to:

```
            <button onClick={(event) => { addToCart}}>Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: {addtoCart} is sufficient

Comment: Still Not working. Even if I tried to copy a normal button to check in this component it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your **addToCart** function to *arrow* function:

```js
 const addToCart = (event) => {

        console.log(event);

        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
            item: {

                id: id,

                title: title,
                image: image,
                price: price,
                rating: rating
            },
        });

    };
```

Comment: ` function addToCart(event) ` works even without converting it to a arrow function

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with your code. I'd suspect there's something going on with the `useStateValue` function.

I'd look in a couple of places:

- Is the `dispatch` being returned from `useStateValue` definitely a dispatcher?
- Is the 'ADD_TO_CART' action being picked up properly by your reducer? There might be a typo somewhere.

Comment: I also checked your code in codepen and worked properly.
https://codepen.io/Pourhadi/pen/RwKJrav

I agree with @cd3k i guess something is wrong with your dispatcher or StateProvider.